to obtain the data dictionary and ERD for D365 tables
I have created a data lake with data ingested directly from D365. We have about 250 tables but we do have data dictionary or ERD for these tables. As such, I do not how to link the tables to form reports and dashboards.
I am hoping someone could enlighten me so that I able to obtain the data dictionary and ERD.
